# LTspice: Not getting expected values

Tags: ltspice

Below is the circuit in question, with the result I'm getting (sorry for poor notation, I'm pretty new to this):

[image]

Source V1 is 100sin(50000t+90deg) and V2 is 100sin(50000t+180deg)

I'm sure I am making an obvious mistake, but when I analyze the circuit by hand, I get that the steady-state voltage across the inductor should have an amplitude of roughly 118V. For a reason that escapes me, LTspice shows this amplitude as roughly 108V. What am I missing?

Work below: [image]

Comment: Do you have 10 V across your resistor R1?

Comment: Your simulation says 100V on both sine sources but your question says 10 on V2.

Comment: Just a typo, sorry

Comment: V2 is flipped so you have 180° phase shift and then you add another 180°? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is flipped intentionally.

Comment: You should probably show your hand calculations.

Comment: Oh man... I am adding my work now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I was putting the angular frequency into LTspice, rather than the frequency. So in LTspice, set 7957.75 Hz as the frequency of both sources and the results match the calculations.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing \$ 2 \pi \$ in the impedance calculations. See if the new values below correct your issue.
$$ Z_L = \omega L = 2 \pi f L = 2 \pi \;50k \; 100 \mu \approx 31.42 \Omega $$

$$ Z_C = {1 \over{\omega C}} = {1 \over {2 \pi f C}} = {1 \over{2\pi \;50k \; 2\mu}} \approx 1.59 \Omega $$

This is why showing all your work is important, even for trivial things like figuring out the impedance of a capacitor & inductor.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! In the simulation, I was putting 50000Hz as the frequency for both sine functions, when I should have been putting 50000/(2π)